# How do I diagonalize the following BdG Hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I want to diagonalize the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k
 \left(
  \begin{matrix}
   c_{k\uparrow}^{\dagger} & c_{k\downarrow}^{\dagger} & c_{-k\uparrow} & c_{-k\downarrow}
  \end{matrix} 
 \right)
 \left(
 \begin{matrix}
   \epsilon_k+h & S_k & 0 & -\Delta \\
   S_k^* & \epsilon_k-h & \Delta & 0 \\
   0 & \Delta^* & -\epsilon_k-h & S_k^* \\
   -\Delta^* & 0 & S_k & -\epsilon_k+h \\
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
 \left(
 \begin{matrix}
 c_{k\uparrow} \\ c_{k\downarrow} \\ c_{-k\uparrow}^{\dagger} \\ c_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}
 \end{matrix}
 \right)
\end{equation}
where $c_k$ is fermion,and $S_{-k} = -S_k$.
But the transformation matrix obtained by solving the eigenvectors is so complicated that I can't normalize it. How can I obtain the simplest formalization.
Furthermore, I have learned another argument, the quasiparticles should be coupled by particles and holes, and we can determine the coupling form by Heisenberg equation of motion. For my Hamiltonian, Heisenberg equation of motion give a coulping form of 3 operators, but the eigenvectors are coupled by 4 opertors,so which one is right?

Comment: Could you add the determinant and the eigenvectors of this 4-by-4 matrix? Superficially, it looks rather simple and should allow exact solutions.

Comment: It's just an idea and I don't know it'll actually work out, but I did something similar for a 2x2 (real) matrix in that case starting by writing the transformation matrix as a rotation matrix and determining the angles from that was easier than normalizing the eigenvectors. For a hermitian matrix you just need to add a phase factor to the 4D rotation matrix?

Comment: @Wihtedeka 4-by-4 transformation matrix has a lot more parameters it is a rotation in 4-dimensional space (unlike 2-by-2 matrix, which describes rotation about a fixed axis, parametrized by one angle).

Comment: Is the first part of the question just about how to find the eigenvectors? Mathematica gives closed expressions for both eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which are somewhat long but not terribly complicated. Normalization can always be found, but there is really no point in working really hard to get a nice expression.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks for your reply,I have solved the exact eigenvectors  by Mathematica, but the results are really complicated.The following are the Mathematica codes and you can run it in your computer if you are free.

Comment: A1 = {{E + h, S, 0, -D]}, {Conjugate[S], E - h, D, 0}, {0, Conjugate[D], -E - h, Conjugate[S]}, {-Conjugate[D], 0, S, -E+ h}} 
P = Eigenvectors[A1]

Comment: @RogerVadim Thanks, the  determinant have indeed exact solutions ,but I aim to obtain the bogoliubov transformation coefficients ,the complicated results are bad for my calculations. And can you help me with the second question?